# How to fetch key, value pairs of a dictionary encapsulated inside a string?

Tags: python

In the Python file, write a program to perform a GET request on the route  which contains a data key and the value is a string which contains items in the format: key=STRING, age=INTEGER. here need to count how many items exist that have an age equal to or greater than 50, and print this final value.

Example Input
{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}

Example Output
2

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the `split` function? You could split the initial string by "," and loop over each item of the resulting array. In the loop you split again by "=" which will give you a new array (let's call it `item_parts`). When `item_parts[0]` is equal to `"age"` you check if `item_parts[1] >= 50`.

```
total = 0
initial_value = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"
for item in initial_value.split(","):
    item_parts = item.strip().split("=")  # strip removes any space
    if item_parts[0] == "age" and int(item_parts[1]) >= 50:
        total = total + 1
print(total)
```

Answer (score 5):

As you probably know the data format is given in [json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). So firstly we would like to parse the data into a plain python dictionary

```
import json
output = YOUR_GET_STATEMENT
output_dict = json.loads(output)
```

Now you have a plain python dictionary which has the given string("key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47") as a value with the key "data".
You can now use simple string manipulation to filter you data.

```
# count the occurences of age > 50
count = 0
values = output_dict['data'].replace(' ','').split(',')
for value in values:
    if not 'age' in value:
        continue
    age = int(value.split('=')[1])
    if age > 50:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```py
data={"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}
count=0
for i,value in enumerate(data["data"].split(","),0):
    if(i%2==1) and int(value.strip()[4:])>=50:
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Output:

```
2
```